# SQL Server CE : questions about working offline

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I heard of SQL Server CE but I wonder how do I apply it to my current window app + SQL Server?

Understanding: if the window app failed to connect to the hosting server (SQL Server Express) through internet, then all data key in through offline mode will be saved in client's PC in SQL Server CE and it will be stored in my client PC. Data keyed in during offline mode will then be PUSHED to the server once back to ONLINE.

Question:

1. If I have 3 GB of data in server (SQL Server Express), when my client launch the window app for the first time, will it load all the data from the server to my client pc's SQL Server CE? Is the Data in server must always tally with the data in client PC SQL Server CE? If the answer is YES, then it will surely be taking up a lot of time.
2. Could you share me any SQL Server CE sample project on this which it has CRUD transaction with database. I have search online but found no sample project on this.

Please kindly inform me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to you first point:

If you are talking about using RDA then this would be the case yes. According to [this thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/30b67198-b8d4-4ed5-b8c6-8f183bd2366a) RDA is only good for small databases as it has to pull the whole table always. Alternatively you might want to have a look at Sync Services for ADO .NET. Here is [a tutorial to get started](http://keithelder.net/2007/09/23/sync-services-for-sql-server-compact-edition-3-5-in-visual/). Further down that article there is a piece of code setting the sync direction to bidirectional however you can also set it to [UploadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.syncdirection.aspx) which sounds like what you want.